# connection refused

Tags: python, sockets

What causes the folowing problem:

```
>>> s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s
<socket._socketobject object at 0x104a7a670>
>>> gethostname()
'MacBook-Air-user.local'
>>> s.connect((gethostname(), 4444))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
>>> s.connect((gethostname(), 4444))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> s.bind((gethostname(), 4446))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

On the system:

```
MacBook-Air-user:source user$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Air-user.local 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Nothing listening on that port, or firewall/connectivity problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to open a network connection to your computer on port 4444, but there is no server listening on that port

see the socket example at http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example

Answer (score 1):

It should be [`socket.gethostname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html%E2%80%8E).