# Invalid Argument Follows Connection Refused in Python Sockets

Tags: python, sockets

Please see the example output at:
[connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394950/connection-refused)

The question I have is why the first call to s.connect() throws "Connection Refused", but the second call throws "Invalid Argument". It's like the first call put the socket object s into some kind of error state. Is there a way to reset it?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you ask that at [connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394950/connection-refused) or include the necessary code in this question.

Comment: The only options in the original post were to edit the question or post an answer.  For some reason, this option to add a comment was not available.  I thought about editing the question, but that seemed to change the content of the thread, and I wasn't posting an answer so this seemed the best course of action.  Sorry if I didn't do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling this:

```
s.connect((gethostname(), 4444))
```

`gethostname()` involves more than just connecting to server. It initializes the variables for the socket.

Next time you call `connect`, `s` already have a value, but invalid. So, you get `Invalid argument`.

Note: `s.connect()` actually calls `connect()` with `s` as the first argument, as connect is defines as `def connect(self, ...)`.

Comment: From the top of the example output, gethostname() just returns a string, which is passed into connect().  Do you mean that connect() initializes socket variables?  Is there a way to "clear" the socket so that the next connect() call won't throw Invalid Argument?

Comment: One way I've found to get around this is to re-create the socket variable s each time.  So before each connect() I do:  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)  But that seems wasteful and inefficient.  Is this the best way to go?

Comment: You may have to create a new socket.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that Python will garbage collect any old socket() objects that are replaced by new ones?

Comment: Yes, it should do that as you are resuing the same variable.