# python socket connection refused on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, sockets

This is not a duplicate of [connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394950/connection-refused). This questions asks about the difference between `MacOS` and `Windows`. In addition the firewall on my `Mac` is off.

I'm trying to communicate with a device through a socket. The code is written in `python`. For some reason if I run my code on `Windows` everything works, however if I do it on a `Mac` it doesn't. A colleague of mine wrote the same code in `C` and ran it on a `Mac` and had no issues. Does anybody know what could be the issue?

I can provide more details if needed. Just let me know which ones.

**EDIT**

Here is the code

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, ip_addr, port):
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr
        self.port = port

    def say_hi(self):
        msg = [254, 49, 0]
        ret = self.send_msg(msg)
        msg = [254, 29]
        return self.send_msg(msg)

    def say_bye(self):
        msg = [254, 49, 0]
        ret = self.send_msg(msg)
        msg = [254, 30]
        return self.send_msg(msg)

    def get_status(self):
        msg = [254, 49, 0]
        ret = self.send_msg(msg)
        msg = [254, 16]
        return self.send_msg(msg)

    def send_msg(self, msg):
        msg = ''.join(chr(i) for i in msg)
        s = socket.create_connection((self.ip_addr , self.port))
        s.sendall(msg)
        ret = s.recv(1)
        s.close()
        return ord(ret)
```

Here is the error that I'm getting:

`[Errno 61] Connection refused`

The error occurs at line:

`s = socket.create_connection((self.ip_addr , self.port))`

**EDIT 2**

`ip_addr='172.24.176.46', port='2101'`

I'm able to access the address. Here are results from `ping`

```
$ ping 172.24.176.46    
PING 172.24.176.46 (172.24.176.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.24.176.46: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.495 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.176.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.398 ms
64 bytes from 172.24.176.46: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.452 ms
^C
```

**EDIT 3**

I found a code that works and it works on Windows as well as on a Mac. I will provide it below, but what essentially I do is that I create a connection during class initialization (i.e. in `__init__`) and **don't** close a connection in `send_msg`. Here is my question: is it safe and proper to do it this way? It doesn't seem like a good approach not to close a connection. I would appreciate any help with this. My new code is below.

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, ip_addr, port):
        self.ip_addr = ip_addr
        self.port = port
        self.socket = socket.create_connection((self.ip_addr , self.port))

    def say_hi(self):
        msg = [254, 49, 0]
        ret = self.send_msg(msg)
        msg = [254, 29]
        return self.send_msg(msg)

    def say_bye(self):
        msg = [254, 49, 0]
        ret = self.send_msg(msg)
        msg = [254, 30]
        return self.send_msg(msg)

    def get_status(self):
        msg = [254, 49, 0]
        ret = self.send_msg(msg)
        msg = [254, 16]
        return self.send_msg(msg)

    def send_msg(self, msg):
        msg = ''.join(chr(i) for i in msg)
        self.socket.sendall(msg)
        ret = self.socket.recv(1)
        return ord(ret)
```

Comment: Some of your code posted might help..

Comment: @abccd Added code.

Comment: See this post: [connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394950/connection-refused) most likely you just need to disable your Mac's firewall

Comment: What is the value of `self.ip_addr`?  Does your Mac have access to that address?

Comment: @abccd My firewall is off and my question is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394950/connection-refused. Provided my reasoning in the most recent edit.

Comment: @larsks Just added more explanations. See EDIT 2

Comment: I rather doubt this has anything to do with the python code.  Try `nc 172.24.176.46 2101` (or you can use `telnet 172.24.176.46 2101` if you don't have `nc`).

Comment: @GilHamilton What would it tell me if I run these commands?

Comment: @abccd Added code that works, but can't explain why not closing a connection is a good approach.

Comment: @larsks Added code that works, but can't explain why not closing a connection is a good approach.

Comment: @GilHamilton Added code that works, but can't explain why not closing a connection is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests on my Mac, you cannot use the same socket to listen. There might be a way for the sockets to be used this way, if there I would recommend you read 
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto

I could only get python to connect using two different sockets and creating the client and the server separately. For the server the code looks something like:

```
      server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
      server.bind(('', self.port))
      server.listen(1)
      connection, client_addr = server.accept()
      connection.recv(1024)
      connection.close()
      server.close()
```

For the client the code looks something like:

```
      client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
      try:
          client.connect(('10.6.6.11', 2101))
      except Exception:
          print 'Connection failed'
          sys.exit(1)
      client.sendall(msg)
      client.close()
```

You would have to fill in the blanks for anything else you might want to modify. You can remove that try catch if you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot use the same socket to listen"? Do you mean I cannot call `client.recv(1)`?

Comment: I tried your code. It didn't work. I'm still getting 'Connection refused' message

Comment: You need to use two different sockets. You cant send and receive on port 2101 it seems. If you are receiving on 2101 you have to use a different socket to send that data to the 2101 port that is listening. According to python documentation recv() should for best match with hardware and network realities, the value of bufsize should be a relatively small power of 2, for example, 4096.

Comment: If you edit connection.read() to connection.recv(1024) you should be able to have the client and the server talking to each other. I just finished writing the test right now.

Comment: The issue is that I cannot edit the server. It is running on the device and I cannot edit code on the device.

Comment: Added code that works, but can't explain why not closing a connection is a good approach.

Comment: FYI: `SO_REUSEADDR` has no effect unless you're explicitly binding a port. So you almost never need to use it on a client, since you're usually using an automatically allocated port on that side and such a port will never be in use.

Comment: Ah thank you. I mostly write custom servers, I wasn't sure if clients needed to specify it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code worked fine for me (on a MAC) when I put a small main loop after it.

```
d = Device('127.0.0.1', 2101)
for n in range(5):
    d.say_hi()
    d.get_status()
    d.say_bye()
```

However, your new design is much closer to good. No, *not* closing the connection at all is not a good approach, but closing it, then instantly recreating it is also not a good design.

How about just adding a close function and calling that when you're finished with the object?

```
def close(self):
    self.socket.close()
```

So for example my code would then become:

```
d = Device('127.0.0.1', 2101)
for n in range(5):
    d.say_hi()
    d.get_status()
    d.say_bye()
d.close()
```

(It is also possible to add a `__del__` destructor that will get called automatically after the object is no longer being referenced but that is generally a bad idea because it won't necessarily get called until the garbage collector runs, which could be next month. In the meantime that socket descriptor would remain open.)